# wxDialog is not modal after 3 level on MacOS

Tags: wxwidgets

`wxDialog` is not modal after 3 level on MacOS

1. Launch a `wxDialog::ShowModal()` from `wxFrame`.
2. Launch 2nd `wxDialog::ShowModal()` from 1st `wxDialog`
3. Launch 3rd `wxDialog::ShowModal()` from 2nd `wxDialog`

Result: 3rd `wxDialog` is not Modal anymore. 
Note* I am using wx3.1 on MacOS 10.11 and 10.13. It was working good in wx3.0.

Instead of 3rd `wxDialog`, we can launch `wxMessageBox`/`wxMessageDialog`. Issue is there with these popup also

Logged defect: https://trac.wxwidgets.org/ticket/18204

Sample minimal.cpp

```
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// Name:        minimal.cpp
// Purpose:     Minimal wxWidgets sample
// Author:      Julian Smart
// Modified by:
// Created:     04/01/98
// Copyright:   (c) Julian Smart
// Licence:     wxWindows licence
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

// ============================================================================
// declarations
// ============================================================================

// ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
// headers
// ----------------------------------------------------------------------------

// For compilers that support precompilation, includes "wx/wx.h".
#include "wx/wxprec.h"

#ifdef __BORLANDC__
    #pragma hdrstop
#endif

// for all others, include the necessary headers (this file is usually all you
// need because it includes almost all "standard" wxWidgets headers)
#ifndef WX_PRECOMP
    #include "wx/wx.h"
#endif

// ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
// resources
// ----------------------------------------------------------------------------

// the application icon (under Windows it is in resources and even
// though we could still include the XPM here it would be unused)
#ifndef wxHAS_IMAGES_IN_RESOURCES
    #include "../sample.xpm"
#endif

// ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
// private classes
// ----------------------------------------------------------------------------

// Define a new application type, each program should derive a class from wxApp
class MyApp : public wxApp
{
public:
    // override base class virtuals
    // ----------------------------

    // this one is called on application startup and is a good place for the app
    // initialization (doing it here and not in the ctor allows to have an error
    // return: if OnInit() returns false, the application terminates)
    virtual bool OnInit() wxOVERRIDE;
};

// Define a new frame type: this is going to be our main frame
class MyFrame : public wxFrame
{
public:
    // ctor(s)
    MyFrame(const wxString& title);
    virtual ~MyFrame(){}
    // event handlers (these functions should _not_ be virtual)
    void OnClick(wxCommandEvent& event);

private:

};


wxIMPLEMENT_APP(MyApp);

// ============================================================================
// implementation
// ============================================================================

// ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
// the application class
// ----------------------------------------------------------------------------

// 'Main program' equivalent: the program execution "starts" here
bool MyApp::OnInit()
{
    // call the base class initialization method, currently it only parses a
    // few common command-line options but it could be do more in the future
    if ( !wxApp::OnInit() )
        return false;

    // create the main application window
    MyFrame *frame = new MyFrame("Minimal wxWidgets App");

    // and show it (the frames, unlike simple controls, are not shown when
    // created initially)
    frame->Show(true);

    // success: wxApp::OnRun() will be called which will enter the main message
    // loop and the application will run. If we returned false here, the
    // application would exit immediately.
    return true;
}

// Sample Dialog Test
static int count = 1;

class MyDialog: public wxDialog
{
public:
    MyDialog(wxWindow* parent)
    : wxDialog(parent, wxID_ANY, wxString::Format("My Dialog %d", count))
    {
        count++;
        wxSizer* pSizer = new wxBoxSizer(wxVERTICAL);
        pSizer->AddSpacer(30);

        wxButton* pButton = new wxButton(this, wxID_ANY, "Click Button");
        pButton->Bind(wxEVT_BUTTON, & MyDialog::OnClick, this);
        pSizer->Add(pButton);

        SetSizer(pSizer);
        Layout();
    }

    virtual ~MyDialog()
    {

    }

    private:
    void OnClick(wxCommandEvent& event)
    {
        MyDialog dlg(this);
        dlg.ShowModal();
        event.Skip();
    }


};

// ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
// main frame
// ----------------------------------------------------------------------------

// frame constructor
MyFrame::MyFrame(const wxString& title)
       : wxFrame(NULL, wxID_ANY, title)
{
    wxSizer* pSizer = new wxBoxSizer(wxVERTICAL);
    pSizer->AddSpacer(30);

    wxButton* pButton = new wxButton(this, wxID_ANY, "Click Button");
    pButton->Bind(wxEVT_BUTTON, & MyFrame::OnClick, this);
    pSizer->Add(pButton);

    SetSizer(pSizer);
    Layout();
}

void MyFrame::OnClick(wxCommandEvent& event)
{
    MyDialog dlg(this);
    dlg.ShowModal();
    event.Skip();
}
```

Comment: if you can modify the dialogs sample and check whether it works or not - it would be great. If it doesn't work there, please create a ticket on trac.wxwidgets.org and attach a `patch to the dialogs sample` with instructions on how to reproduce the problem. DO NOT attach the whole sample. If the sample will work - what is different in your code?

Comment: It's very simple, just create 3 dialog in a chain and check the behavior of 3rd dialog

Comment: I understand, but you need to have a way to reproduce a problem in order to create a ticket. And it will be a code that will assure that the problem is resolved. The easiest way is to submit a patch to one of the samples - in this case the dialogs one. And since you already found an issue it will be really easy for you to do.

Comment: Added the minimal sample to reproduce the issue

Comment: Does anyone has any idea for fix